# documentId resolving code doesn't get executed XPages

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, ssjs

In my XPage I need to set a data source (Domino document)

I try to do it as follows:

```
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument var="requestDocument" action="openDocument" databaseName="#{javascript:  print('db ok'); return database.getFilePath();}"
        documentId="#{javascript:
        print('heloooo');
           var conclusion = database.getDocumentByUNID(doc_source.getDocument().getParentDocumentUNID());
           var oConclusion = new OsnovaUI_document(conclusion);
           var requestDoc = oConclusion.getMainDocument();

           print('docID: ' + requestDoc.getUniversalID());

           return requestDoc.getUniversalID();
           }">

    </xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>
```

The thing I've noticed is that code section in `documentId` doesn't get executed. At all. That's why I've put `heloooo` in there. However, the `databaseName` works as expected. In console I always see

```
09.03.2020 00:52:11   HTTP JVM: db ok
```

But not heloooo :(

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: The code in documentId probably is not running.  There is no other code being run before the DominoDocument action -- where has doc_source been defined?  As well what is Osonava_UI?  Remove this code and the print statement will probably work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely cause is `ignoreRequestParams` is not set to `true`. Unless you set that, the data source is retrieving all specifics about which document to edit based on the URL query string parameters (the HTTP request parameters). As a result, the URL query string parameters take precedence, and in the case of nothing being set, that means "use a new document". If you've defined that the URL query string parameters should take precedence, running your code to merely ignore it afterwards is inefficient. As a result, `action="openDocument"` is also being ignored - if you have a docId in the query string it will open that, otherwise it will create a new document.

`documentId` can only get processed once, when the page first loads. Depending on whether the datasource is bound to a panel or an XPage / Custom Control, it will run before the `beforePageLoad` event as well. So runtime binding (`#{javascript:...`) has no effect. `${javascript:...` will avoid confusion.

Error handling may help identify if there is an error. XPages OpenLog Logger is one of the most pervasive (disclaimer, I'm the author) https://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20OpenLog%20Logger.

Answer (score 2):

Change documentId to be computed on page load ($) and not dynamically (#):

```
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument var="requestDocument" action="openDocument">
        <xp:this.documentId><![CDATA[${javascript:
           var conclusion = database.getDocumentByUNID(doc_source.getDocument().getParentDocumentUNID());
           var oConclusion = new OsnovaUI_document(conclusion);
           var requestDoc = oConclusion.getMainDocument();

           print('docID: ' + requestDoc.getUniversalID());

           return requestDoc.getUniversalID();
        }]]></xp:this.documentId>
    </xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>
```

The databaseName is not required if the database is itself.